# Table in LaTeX appearing in middle of next page

Tags: floats, positioning

I've inserted a table in my LaTeX document and have used `\center` to horizontally align it to the centre of the page. However, it's appearing a page after where it should, is both horizontally and vertically aligned to the centre and appears after some text which it should precede.

What's going wrong?

EDIT: Edited to add a Minimal Working Example (though, given that I don't know what could be causing the problem, I can't guarantee minimality).

```
\large
\textbf{Section 2}
\\

\normalsize

\textbf{Description of section}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\center
\caption{Sample output}
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=3cm]{/Users/Matt/Desktop/Figures/2.jpg}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\textbf{Hello}. Below are the results. \\

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption} 
\center
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline \hline
A & B & C \\
\hline
1 & a & A \\
2 & b & B \\
3 & c & C \\
4 & d & D \\
5 & e & E \\
6 & f & F \\
7 & g & G \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

%Section 2 end

\Large
\textbf{Title}

\large
\textbf{Section 3}
\
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Specifically, we need to see what optional arguments you're using if you're using the table environment. Something like `\begin{table}[p]` (page) could be causing the table to be set on its own page. If you just used `[h]` (here) then try adding `t` (top) to it, as if the table runs over a page with just `[h]` it can default to page.

Comment: Hmm, now the table doesn't appeared centred vertically, but it does appear after "Section 3"

Comment: Apologies for this travesty of a question. I've corrected the problem by adding "\\" where appropriate.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but doesn't it need to be `\centering` instead of just `\center`?. If you don't want a table to float beyond a certian point use the `placeins`package's command `\FloatBarrier` where appropriate

Comment: Your code is not a complete MWE- please append it so that it includes the `documentclass` & pre-amble, and can be compiled without editing. Also, using `\\` outside of the `tabular` environment in the way you have is not appropriate- I recommend reading `The Not so short guide to LaTeX` for an overview of the basics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After adapting the code snippet provided to be compilable by adding the usual preamble: `\documentclass{}`... `\usepackage{}`...`\begin{document}` it still does not show the problem that you mention.  I suspect that since the `table` environment is a float, it ends up on a page by itself, in which case the default is to vertically center it on the page.  An excellent discussion can be found at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

To modify this behavior so that the `table` is at the top of the page, you need to set distance from top of page to first float by adjusting the length defined by `\@fptop`  as per [Vertical layout of float pages](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-vertposfp).

The code below produces a table at the top of Page 2, but if you comment out the `\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}` it will display the default behavior and be vertically centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Caption} 
\center
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\hline \hline
A & B & C \\
\hline
1 & a & A \\
2 & b & B \\
3 & c & C \\
4 & d & D \\
5 & e & E \\
6 & f & F \\
7 & g & G \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```